# How to format an array like String [] {a, b, c, ... n} for an unknown number of arguments?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I pass an unknown number of arguments to a String array.
Put simply, I need a generalization of this:

```
private String[] contactsFirstNameData = new String[] {
      "Emerson", "Lake", "Palmer"
};
```

So I can express it like this or similar:

```
LinkedList<String> l = new LinkedList<>();
l.add("Emerson"); l.add("Lake"); l.add("Palmer");
private String[] contactsFirstNameData = new String[] {
    //Some function to pass l's elements
}
```

Comment: This will be tricky as shown because `contactsFirstNameData` is static data and (hence) is defined before `l` which is instance data.

Comment: @dave `LinkedList<String> l = new LinkedList<>();` also static :P

Comment: @CommonMan I think `l` would need to have a `static` qualifier to be static, don't you?

Comment: @dave yes, but still it will not solve OP's problem.

Comment: Dave, they're different but "equivalent" pieces of code... That's what I meant. Sorry for the confusion. Good observation, though.

Comment: on a side note. `l` is the most terrible variable name. Right up there with `O`. Looks like 1 and 0

Comment: It was for the sake of the example, it's not the actual list's name, but I appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] contactsFirstNameData = l.toArray(String[]::new);
```

---

If your field is `static final`, you can initialize it in a static block:-

```
private static final String[] contactsFirstNameData;

static {
    LinkedList<String> l = new LinkedList<>();
    l.add("Emerson");
    l.add("Lake");
    l.add("Palmer");
    contactsFirstNameData = l.toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

---

If it's just `final` and not static, you can use constructor:-

```
private final String[] contactsFirstNameData;

public MyClass() {
    LinkedList<String> l = new LinkedList<>();
    l.add("Emerson");
    l.add("Lake");
    l.add("Palmer");
    contactsFirstNameData = l.toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist thank you, you'll get your chance to upvote on my future answers :)

Comment: Thanks @Kartik, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: @ruakh. The first edit of this answer was not nearly so polished. I've removed my obsolete comment.